# Copy only regular files from one directory to another

Tags: files, cp, file-copy

I'd like to copy a content of directory 1 to directory 2. 
However,
I'd like to only copy files (and not directories) from my directory 1. 
How can I do that?

```
cp dir1/* dir2/*
```

then I still have the directories issue.

Also, all my files don't have any extension, so `*.*` won't do the trick.

Comment: Don't know what extensions have to do with it.

Comment: `cp dir1/* dir2` or `cp -t dir2 dir1/*`

Comment: @richard There's a fairly common habit coming from the DOS world of not using extensions for directories, which still survives to some extent, leading some people to assume that if there's a dot then it isn't a directory and vice versa.

Comment: ok but still not relevent.

Comment: Avoid using quotes, neither simple nor double

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
cp dir1/* dir2
```

`cp` will not copy directories unless explicitly told to do so (with `--recursive` for example, see `man cp`).

**Note 1:** `cp` will most likely exit with a non-zero status, but the files will have been copied anyway. This may be an issue when chaining commands based on exit codes:`&&`, `||`, `if cp -r dir1/* dir2; then ...`, etc. (Thanks to [contrebis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73248) for [their comment on that issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101916/copy-only-regular-files-from-one-directory-to-another/101923?noredirect=1#comment459686_101923))

**Note 2**: `cp` expects the last parameter to be a single file name or directory. There really should be no wildcard `*` after the name of the target directory. `dir2\*` will be expanded by the shell just like `dir1\*`. Unexpected things *will* happen:

- If `dir2` is empty and depending on your shell and settings:

  - you may just get an error message, which is the best case scenario.
  - `dir2/*` will be taken literally (looking for a file/directory named `*`), which will probably lead to an error, too, unless `*` actually exists.
  - `dir2/*` it will just be removed from the command entirely, leaving `cp dir1/*`. Which, depending on the expansion of `dir1/*`, may even destroy data:

    - If `dir1/*` matches only one file or directory, you will get an error from `cp`.
    - If `dir1/*` matches exactly two files, one will be overwritten by the other (*Bad*).
    - If `dir/*` matches multiple files and the last match is a, you will get an error message.
    - If the last match of `dir/*` is a directory all other matches will be moved into it.
- If `dir2` is not empty, it again depends:

  - If the last match of `dir2/*` is a directory, `dir1/*` and the other matches of `dir2/*` will be moved into.
  - If the last match of `dir2/*` is a file, you probably will get an error message, *unless* `dir1/*` matches only one file.

Comment: `$ cp dir1/* dir2` --> `cp: dir1/isadir is a directory (not copied).` exits with status 1 for me.

Comment: Yes, it does exit with status 1 for me, too. But even so, `cp` does copy the files matching `dir1/*` on every system I checked: Arch Linux, Ubuntu 14.04, OpenBSD 3.9 and 5.5, SuSE Linux 8.1, FreeBSD 6.2, Solaris 8, 9 and 10 (where `cp` actually exits with code 2). So this behavior is neither new (SuSE 8.1 is from 2002) nor is it limited to Linux. `cp` exits with a non-zero exit code because it could not do *everything* it was told to do. That does not mean it does *nothing*.

Comment: Sure, I thought worth noting because if you're chaining commands together with `&&` this can cause a problem. I was trying to something like this though I can't remember the context now.

Comment: This does not copy hidden files.

Comment: @felwithe Whether `*` includes hidden files or how to include hidden files depends on the shell. If the `*` does not include hidden files, you can match them with `.*`. Note that this will include `.` and `..` on `bash` and `dash` but not on `zsh`. In the context of this answer you can get away with `cp dir1/* dir1/.* dir2` because `.` and `..` are directories and will not be copied. `zsh` can also be made to include hidden files with `*(D)`.

Comment: @felwithe I have just tried it, works for hidden files with `cp dir1/.* dir2`.

Answer (score 14):

It's the shell that expands wildcards, not the commands. So `cp dir1/* dir2/*` first expands the two wildcards, then calls `cp` on the result. This is not at all what you apparently expect: depending on how many files there are already in `dir2`, `dir2/*` may expand to one or more argument. The command `cp` doesn't know which of its arguments came from expanding the first pattern and which ones came from expanding the second pattern. It expects its last argument to be the name of the destination directory. Thus, to copy all the files from the directory `dir1` into the directory `dir2`, the last argument must be the directory `dir2`:

```
cp dir1/* dir2
```

Since `*` matches all files, `cp` attempts to copy all files. This includes directories: directories are files too. It skips directories, but reports an error. It copies the content of special files such as named pipes (something had better be writing to them, or `cp` will block), etc.

To copy only *regular* files, you need to restrict the matching. In zsh, you can use the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `.` for that:

```
cp dir1/*(.) dir2
```

Other shells don't have this. You can use the `find` command to filter on file types. Assuming that you're running non-embedded Linux or Cygwin:

```
find dir1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp -t dir2 {} +
```

On Linux, FreeBSD and OSX:

```
find dir1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -I {} cp {} dir2
```

Comment: Is there a reason to specify `-maxdepth 1`. Also, is there a way to recursively copy and preserve the original directory hierarchy in the destination directory?

Comment: @Abdull Without `-maxdepth 1`, the `find` command would recurse into subdirectories, which was not desired here. If you want to copy the whole directory tree including subdirectories, it's a completely different question, and the answer is a lot simpler: `cp -a dir1 dir2`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'rsync' instead of 'cp'

```
rsync -vt dir1/* dir2/
```

It cleaner and in some cases faster

Answer (score 0):

Below is the command to copy file from source to destination directory.

1. Go to source folder then write below command:

   `$ cp fileName destination directory path`

Example:

```
cp publichOT.sh  /data/home/useradmin
```